# Finding Spectral Radius of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Find the Spectral Radius of $A=$
$\mbox{} \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & -c & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$

After going through the motions, I got that the $-x^{3}-c^{2}x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $-x(x^{2}+c^{2})$

Now C is supposed to be in $\mathbb{R}$ while $A \in \mathbb{C}$

When I use the quadratic formula, I get that 2iC=0, and by the definition the spectral radius is the largest absolute value of the eigenvalues.

So what am I to make of the results of the quadratic formula? On the right path?

Comment: Care to explain how you get $2iC = 0$ rather than $x = something$ from the quadratic formula?

Comment: Okay, totally understand mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Then would $i c$ be the largest possible eigenvalue?

Answer (score 2):

You're heading in the right direction, but your [characteristic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) is not right.

\[\mathrm{det}(A-xI) =\mathrm{det}\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1-x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -x & c & 0 \\ 0 & -c & -x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -x \end{array} \right].\]
Once you get that, you can factor it into linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$ to find the eigenvalues.

Note that $1$ is always an eigenvalue, since
\[\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & -c & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{c}
 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right]\] so your spectral radius can never be less than $1$.